# Facebook login plugin button edit CSS

Tags: css, facebook-login

I integrated facebook login button,

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-size="large" ></fb:login-button>
```

is there any way I can change its styling? width, hight etc via css? assigning it a `class` and accessing via class on CSS or adding the `style` attribute did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only choose between the options in the [generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button), but you are not allowed to change the appearance of Social Plugins in any way.

What you can do is use your own button and use [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for the login process. Just check out the docs for example code ans usage, here is a tutorial if the docs are not enough for you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/